# WPF Multiple Triggers & DataTrigger on Button Style

Tags: wpf, button, triggers, styles, datatrigger

Working on a "data entry style" program. After a certain combination of data changes a property IsSaveNeeded (enum: Yes, No) is set to Yes and the Save button is suppose to flash.

I have been able to get the button to flash with a basic button

```
<!--Save Button-->
    <Button Content="   Save&#13;Settings&#13;  to File" x:Name="SaveBtn" Command="{Binding SaveCMD}" Padding="10,5" Margin= "10,0" IsEnabled="{Binding SaveEnabled}" 
            Background="{StaticResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlLightBrushKey}}">
        <Button.Style>
            <Style TargetType="Button">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSaveNeeded}" Value="Yes">
                        <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard x:Name="FlashBackground">
                                <Storyboard BeginTime="00:00:00" RepeatBehavior="Forever" >
                                    <ColorAnimation  Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color" Duration="00:00:00.75" AutoReverse="True" To="Red" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </DataTrigger.EnterActions>

                        <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                            <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="FlashBackground" />
                        </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Button.Style>
    </Button>
```

I have been required to make all the buttons a custom style button.

```
 <!--My Custom Buton-->
<Style x:Key="myBtn" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" />
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource myColorBrush}" />

    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">

                <Grid UseLayoutRounding="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                    <!--Button Content / DropShadow / Border-->
                    <Border Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" CornerRadius="5" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="{StaticResource myColorBrush}">
                        <Border.Effect>
                            <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="4" Direction="330" Color="Black" Opacity="0.2" BlurRadius="4"/>
                        </Border.Effect>
                    </Border>

                    <Border Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" UseLayoutRounding="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                        <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" >
                            <!--<TextBlock.Effect>
                                <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="4" Direction="330" Color="{StaticResource MyColor}" Opacity="0.3" BlurRadius="4"/>
                            </TextBlock.Effect>-->
                        </TextBlock>
                    </Border>
                </Grid>

            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>

    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFC1C1C1" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FFACA8A8" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource myHoverBrush}"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource myColorBrush}"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

I need to add the IsSaveNeeded DataTrigger to this custom button style, myFlashingBtn, but when I do the Flashing works but the other Triggers stop working.

How do I incorporate the IsSaveNeeded Flashing into my custom button style and keep all the Triggers working? MultiTrigger and MultiDataTriggers haven't helped unless I wrote them wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're looking for the `BasedOn` property ([Style.BasedOn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.style.basedon(v=vs.110).aspx)).
This allows you to inherit everything from a specific style and add to it.

```
<!--Save Button-->
<Button Content="   Save&#13;Settings&#13;  to File" x:Name="SaveBtn" Command="{Binding SaveCMD}" Padding="10,5" Margin= "10,0" IsEnabled="{Binding SaveEnabled}" >
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource myBtn}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlLightBrushKey}}"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSaveNeeded}" Value="Yes">
                    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard x:Name="FlashBackground">
                            <Storyboard BeginTime="00:00:00" RepeatBehavior="Forever" >
                                <ColorAnimation  Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color" Duration="00:00:00.75" AutoReverse="True" To="Red" />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>

                    <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                        <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="FlashBackground" />
                    </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

**Edit:** I moved the `Background` to a setter of the Style

Comment: Thanks, but I have tried this, and retried it with your code. The button will do the Triggers but will not Flash, the DataTrigger, with this.

Comment: @Bluto - So if you remove the `BasedOn="{StaticResource myBtn}"` the flashing works? And as soon as you add the `BasedOn="{StaticResource myBtn}"` the style is applied but the flashing doesn't work any longer?

Comment: Correct. Also you have to put the Background Setter in the new Style above.

Comment: @Bluto - Yeah I moved the background setter, and I might've placed it wrong. Should be fine now. A property can't have multiple setters, thats why I used it to the Style, it could be the very thing that solves your issue. If you declare the same property twice you'll see that what ever is put in the `Style.Setter` won't get used.